# Write multiple lines to text

Tags: c

I want to write multiple lines in C , and when I enter a empty line , to exit the writing , so far I'm writing only one word in text...

```
printf("Enter new file name ,or the file which you want to edit: ");
scanf("%s",filename);
snprintf(buffer1, sizeof(buffer1), "C:\\Proiect\\%s.txt", filename);

FILE *OutFile = fopen(buffer1,"w");
scanf("%s",write_in_file);

fprintf(OutFile,"%s",write_in_file);
fclose(OutFile);

printf("File %s created!",filename);
```

EDIT , I don't know why , after I'm running this code , after I 'm writing first word my code is crashing...

```
 printf("Enter new file name ,or the file which you want to edit: ");
 scanf("%s",filename);
 snprintf(buffer1, sizeof(buffer1), "C:\\Proiect\\%s.txt", filename);


 char line[256];
 FILE *OutFile = fopen(buffer1,"w");
  do {
 fgets(line,256,stdin);


fprintf(OutFile,line);


 //Your code to store the line to the file.
 }while(line[0] != '\n');
fclose(OutFile);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets). As the documentations says,

> fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading stops after an EOF or a newline. If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer. A terminating null byte (aq\0aq) is stored after the last character in the buffer.

The only thing you need to remember is that there is an upper bound on the line size. So for instance if the max size of the line your program will accpet is 255(+1 for `\0`), here is what your code should look like

```
char line[256];
do {
     fgets(line,256,stdin);
     //Your code to store the line to the file.
}while(line[0] != '\n')
```

Comment: that's a good idea , but there where you're telling me to write the code to store the line to the file , I'm kinda stuck , because I don't know how to write more then a string to the file !!

Comment: You've already used that piece of code. `fprintf(OutFile,"%s",line);` Close the line after the while loop, is, using the line `fclose(OutFIle)`.

Comment: A couple of mistakes, 1. Open the file before the loop. 2. You don't need the `scanf` in the loop. 3. In the fprintf statement, you need to use `line` instead of `write_in_file`

Comment: if I use line instead of write_in_file , I can't write something in text , nothing is happend

Comment: So that should do. When you want to stop. Just press enter. All the lines will be written to the file.

Comment: but this code doesn't let me to write something , is jumping the loop , I can't  write anything..

Comment: Okay so the problem is because of the first `\n` which you enter after the filename. Change that line to `scanf("%s\n",filename);`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91503/discussion-between-pooja-nilangekar-and-cosmin-oprea).